# How to compress a response returned by Web API HttpClient in .net core 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, httpclient

I have developed a angular SPA application which gives a call to controller action and controller in turn call to  WEB API. I want to compress a response returned by WEB API and send compressed response to client( browser) which will be decompressed by browser automatically. 
I have configured response compression middle ware in startup like below :

```
app.UseResponseCompression()

services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
    options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);

services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        options.EnableForHttps = true;
    });
```

This is working fine, but problem is, **it is compressing each & every
response.**

I only want to return compressed response only from some of my API endpoints.
have tried the same using the **ActionFilter** but no success.

Comment: Clients compress requests, servers compress responses. It is unclear what you're asking. Read [ask] and explain what you expect to see and what you actually see. Also, what is the relevance of HttpClient here?

Comment: `HttpClient` doesn't return anything, it retrieves and posts data. It's not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: @CodeCaster@DavidG Updated the description

Comment: I think you need your API to return compressed response only for some specific URLs?

Comment: Why do you care about not compressing all responses? Surely all compression is a good thing?

Comment: Yes it is but for small request also compression will be done, which is overhead

Comment: @tia Yes Right !

Comment: "which is overhead" - show some numbers.

Comment: @bommelding I have noted down the numbers for small request. Data is compressed efficiently but processing time at client side is increased by 1 sec

Comment: 1 sec per day is not a whole lot. And compared to what?